# Unable to run Kmedo.predict() in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

This is from a jupyter notebook cell running on VSCode - I am new to Python - using 3.10.64

```
kmedo = KMedoids(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1)

kmedo.fit(data_scaled)

data_scaled_copy['kmedoLabels'] = kmedo.predict(data_scaled)
# data_scaled_copy['KMeans_Labels'] = kmeans.predict(data_scaled)

# data['kmedoLabels'] = kmedo.predict(data_scaled)
```

I can't figure out why I get the following error. Is it a package issue and how can I resolve it? It works fine if I use kmeans.predict. What checks can I do?

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> c:\Practice_Case_Study_Clustering.ipynb
> Cell 48' in <cell line: 5>()
>       1 kmedo = KMedoids(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1)
>       3 kmedo.fit(data_scaled)
> ----> 5 data_scaled_copy['kmedoLabels'] = kmedo.predict(data_scaled)
> 
> File
> c:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:420,
> in KMedoids.predict(self, X)
>     416 if self.metric == "seuclidean":
>     417     kwargs["V"] = np.var(
>     418         np.vstack([X, self.cluster_centers_]), axis=0, ddof=1
>     419     )
> --> 420 pd_argmin = pairwise_distances_argmin(
>     421     X,
>     422     Y=self.cluster_centers_,
>     423     metric=self.metric,
>     424     metric_kwargs=kwargs,
>     425 )
>     427 return pd_argmin
> 
> File
> c:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py:791,
> in pairwise_distances_argmin(X, Y, axis, metric, metric_kwargs)
>     788         metric = "sqeuclidean"
>     789         metric_kwargs = {}
> --> 791     indices = PairwiseDistancesArgKmin.compute(
>     792         X=X,
>     793         Y=Y,
>     794         k=1,
>     795         metric=metric,
>     796         metric_kwargs=metric_kwargs,
>     797         strategy="auto",
>     798         return_distance=False,
>     799     )
>     800     indices = indices.flatten()
>     801 else:
>     802     # TODO: once PairwiseDistancesArgKmin supports sparse input matrices and 32 bit,
>     803     # we won't need to fallback to pairwise_distances_chunked anymore.
>     804 
>     805     # Turn off check for finiteness because this is costly and because arrays
>     806     # have already been validated.
> 
> File sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction.pyx:672, in
> sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction.PairwiseDistancesArgKmin.compute()
> 
> File sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction.pyx:1055, in
> sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction.FastEuclideanPairwiseDistancesArgKmin.__init__()
> 
> File sklearn\metrics\_dist_metrics.pyx:1300, in
> sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics.DatasetsPair.get_for()
> 
> File sklearn\metrics\_dist_metrics.pyx:1348, in
> sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics.DenseDenseDatasetsPair.__init__()
> 
> File stringsource:658, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper()
> 
> File stringsource:349, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__()
> 
> ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

Comment: Check the answer out at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778079/valueerror-ndarray-is-not-c-contiguous-in-cython