# ndarray is not C-contiguous using scikit-learn knn.predict

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am triying to call predict function in order to this I have the following code

```
def convert_to_df(obj):
    obj_dic = obj.dict()
    df = pd.DataFrame(obj_dic.values(), index=obj_dic.keys())
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df


@app.get("/get_rating")
def get_rating(features: Features):
    features = convert_to_df(features).T # shape (1, 26)
    return {'rating': Predictor().predict(features)}
```

but I am getting the following error:

> File "stringsource", line 658, in
> View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper   File "stringsource", line 349,
> in View.MemoryView.memoryview.**cinit** ValueError: ndarray is not
> C-contiguous

How can I solve this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Predictor is a knn model trainer with scikit learn

```
def predict(self, features) -> int:
    return self.model.predict(features)
```

Comment: Where's the <explitive> traceback?  Information about the arrays or frames?

Comment: what's this `Predictor'?

Comment: When you report a Python error, it is helpful to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there, including the line that generated the error.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I guessed was explicated, is a Dataframe passed to a scikit knn model.

Wath other information do you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778079/valueerror-ndarray-is-not-c-contiguous-in-cython)

Comment: It isn't work, with the following code features.values.copy(order='C') I have the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of data and traceback information is still not enough. But I'll make a guess.

Let's make a simple dataframe:

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,4)))

In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

`predict` probably uses some compiled code that expect `c-contiguous` data.  If given a dataframe it probably first converts it to an array, such as with `np.array(df)` or effectively:

```
In [35]: df.values
Out[35]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])

In [36]: df.values.flags
Out[36]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

But if you do a transpose the contiguity changes.  This is well known for arrays, and it looks like pandas is compatible:

```
In [37]: df.T.values.flags
Out[37]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

`pandas` `transpose` allows us to specify copy - see its docs:

```
In [38]: df.transpose(copy=True).values.flags
Out[38]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

So using in your code might(???) solve the problem:

```
 features = convert_to_df(features).transpose(copy=True)
```

I can't stress enough that you should include enough information in your question.

Comment: Finnaly I redo the endpoint and I have a problem with the version of scikit learn, I couldn't test your solution, but anyway works, so thanks a lot for you response.

Answer (score 1):

Even if all the columns independently are  > C_CONTIGUOUS : True
The entire df `C_CONTIGUOUS` flag shows as `False`

```py
# this solution worked for me
X, y = np.ascontiguousarray(df[required_cols]), df['labeled']
```

while assigining I converted the required columns